# C# Linq-to-SQL Insert row into datacontext without committing to database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing this Web app that is associated with a Microsoft sql database.

I want the user to be able to insert rows, view rows, and then edit those rows on the page.

When the user clicks a submit button, I want to commit all of the changes that the user made to the database in one large transaction.

Now I have this `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` object and I'm trying to insert a row into it without submitting changes to the database.

how do i do this?

Comment: Then why do you add it to the context in the first place? Do that when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Why? Don't you think there's a better way? Like moving the insert logic to the click of the button?

Comment: I want to be able to perform other operations on the data context before the user decides to commit changes.  I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InsertOnSubmit` shouldn't actually write anything until you call `SubmitChanges()`. Failing that, stick all your objects to add in a list or something, and iterate over them later to insert.